# Set Values by only columns in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to `google apps script` and I want to set some values in a sheet where the values are from other sheet. Problem is, the values are saving as row wise but I want to save it as column wise. Here are my codes,

```
function setKeys() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Key");
    var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Bldng4");

    var getWindows = sheet1.getRange(2, 2, sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
    sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 10, 2, 1, getWindows.length).setValues(getWindows);
}
```

How can I add the values as column wise in `sheet2`? Need this help badly. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the original sheet, with dummy data?

Comment: Sorry I can't. I'm working on my client's sheet and I'm unauthorized to share.

Comment: Even with dummy data? It's hard to help without a file in hand to play with

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to transpose your column vector into a row vector.

Currently your data is in the format `[[1],[2],[3]]`, you want it in the format `[[1,2,3]]`

This can be done fairly easily like this

```
function columnToRowVector(columnVector){
  var rowVector = [];
  rowVector.push([]);
  for (var row = 0; row < columnVector.length; ++row){
    rowVector[0].push(columnVector[row][0])
  }
  return rowVector;
}
```

I have written three small methods for the `getValues()` objects [here](https://github.com/RobinGertenbach/Google-Apps-Script-Utilities/blob/master/Matrix%20Tools.gs) which allow you to create column vectors, range vectors and to the transposition I just mentioned in a more general fashion, feel free to use that if you have to do more transpositions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
var verticalArray = new Array(number of rows you need);
for (var i = 0; i < verticalArray.length - 1; i++) {
  verticalArray [i] = new Array(1);
  verticalArray [i][0] = horizontalArray[i];
}
```

Now you may use the `verticalArray` with `setValues()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by wrapping the array in brackets.

```
     var propLength = Object.keys(tag).length;
     var propKey = Object.keys(tag);
     tagsSheet.getRange(1,1,1,propLength).setValues([propKey]);
```

I had an array like

```
    [containerId, firingTriggerId, consentSettings, name, parameter, workspaceId, fingerprint, type, tagManagerUrl, tagFiringOption, monitoringMetadata, path, accountId, tagId]
```

and I was trying set it across 14 columns with

```
tagsSheet.getRange(1,1,1,14).setValues(propKey)
```

I was reminded about transforming into a 2d array so I used

```
      var prop2d = propKey.map((item,index,array) => array[index] = [item]);
     tagsSheet.getRange(1,1,1,14).setValues(prop2Key)
```

which worked for creating a 2d array however I kept getting the error

```
range is 1 while propKey is 14...
```

The simplest solution which I found was to just wrap the array with []

```
tagsSheet.getRange(1,1,1,14).setValues([propKey])
```

and I got the expected output of my array across 14 columns.